# Good portfolio to be accepted internationally

Tags: packaging

I work as a graphic designer ( package) and I want to apply for abroad, what should I do to make a very good portfolio, which will be accepted internationally . I am aiming for UK,  Canada and Australia.. Please help me about this matter

Answer (score 1):

A good portfolio is already international; good design is good design no matter where you are.

Just focus on showcasing what you consider to be your best work, which highlights your style and your skills.